# objective-c: Expanded from macro

Tags: objective-c, mopub, mmf

in Mopub-SDK for iOS.there is an error in calling "mp_safe_block" method.

**Macro definition:**

```
// Macros for dispatching asynchronously to the main queue
#define mp_safe_block(block, ...) block ? block(__VA_ARGS__) : nil
```

**Called as:**

```
mp_safe_block(complete, NSError.sdkInitializationInProgress, nil);
```

**Error message:**

> Left operand to ? is void, but right operand is of type 'nullptr_t'

maybe this error has nothing to do with the SDK itself. how to fix it ?

PS:
that sdk code run correctly in a new xCode project created by myself. but there is an error in a Xcode-project builded by MMF2(clickTeam fusion)
and this xCode-project version is too old. I updateded setting of Xcode.but it still an error.

Comment: Isn't `complete` supposed to return something? To be honest, using similar macros is just bad practice.

Comment: yes.but that is SDK code.that sdk code  run correctly in a new xCode project create by myself. but there is error in a Xcode-project builded by MMF2(clickTeam fusion).

Comment: What is return type of your `complete`, is it a `void`? you should return something from it.